# Google Sheet SUMIF returning an error! statement

Tags: google-sheets

pretty new to google sheets, my question could seems awkward but i'm struggling with a sumif in google sheets.

I'm using a sumif to sum up some values with a simple condition and i struggle to find the right way to do it. Assuming the documentation i do it well but i must be missing something because the result is always : ERROR!

See the example below

[image]

The example is simple, applying exactly what the documentation says but still not working.

I tried to make the cell format number for the condition, still not working.

I tried to make the condition a string by typing "=1", still not work. I tried to use a cell value in the condition B5 for example, still not working.. I'm desperate, i don't understand why this simple example is still not working.

If someone could help it will save my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that your spreadsheet is using a locale that expects formula arguments to be separated with semicolons instead of commas, like this:

```
=sumif(B5:B10; 1; C5:C10)
```

You can set the locale in ***File > Settings > Locale***.

Comment: Thank you so much, in fact, google sheets automatically add comma to my formula so i never tried to change this because i thought he add the right separator.. But in File > Settings i can't change that.. I'll try to look forward to be able to change that. Thank you again.